# How to return a MAX() value without adding all columns to the Group By clause?

Tags: sql-server

Lets Say I have these Four Tables

A

```
Serial Make Model
A      AA   123
B      AB   222
C      AA   124
```

B

```
HeaderID  OpenDate   Serial
001       1/1/2021   A
002       1/1/2021   B
003       1/2/2021   C
```

C

```
HeaderID  SegmentID JobCode
001       001       1A
001       002       1B
002       003       2A
```

D

```
SegmentID  Cost    Tax    Date  
001        $25.00  $2.00  1/1/2021
002        $10.00  $1.00  1/2/2021
003        $15.00  $1.00  1/3/2021
```

My Code looks like this:

```
SELECT B.HeaderID, A.Serial, A.Make, A.Model, B.OpenDate, C.JobCode, D.Cost + D.Tax AS TotalCost
FROM B
INNER JOIN 
A ON A.Serial = B.Serial
INNER JOIN C
ON C.HeaderID = B.HeaderID
INNER JOIN D
ON D.SegmentID = C.SegmentID
```

This gives me the result of :

```
HeaderID Serial Make Model OpenDate  JobCode Total Cost
001      A      AA   123   1/1/2021  1A      $27.00 
001      A      AA   123   1/1/2021  1B      $11.00
002      B      AB   222   1/1/2021  2A      $16.00
003      C      AA   124   1/2/2021  NULL    NULL
```

I am now being asked to bring in the MAX Date from the D table for each HeaderID. So my new results should be:

```
HeaderID Serial Make Model OpenDate  JobCode Cost    Date
001      A      AA   123   1/1/2021  1A      $27.00  1/2/2021
001      A      AA   123   1/1/2021  1B      $11.00  1/2/2021
002      B      AB   222   1/1/2021  2A      $16.00  1/3/2021
003      C      AA   124   1/2/2021  NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Is there an easy way to simply add this on to the existing query that I have without having to start over from the top? Thanks in advance?

Comment: Use a windowed aggregate? A subquery in the `SELECT` or `FROM` (using `APPLY`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `CTE` like this to get the `MAX` date, then `LEFT` joining it back to your original query should work.

```
;WITH MX
AS (
    SELECT HeaderID, MAX([Date]) AS MaxDate
    FROM C 
    INNER JOIN D
    ON D.SegmentID = C.SegmentID
    GROUP BY HeaderID
    )
SELECT B.HeaderID, A.Serial, A.Make, A.Model, B.OpenDate, C.JobCode, D.Cost + D.Tax AS TotalCost, MX.MaxDate
FROM B
INNER JOIN A 
ON A.Serial = B.Serial
INNER JOIN C
ON C.HeaderID = B.HeaderID
INNER JOIN D
ON D.SegmentID = C.SegmentID
LEFT JOIN MX
ON D.HeaderID = MX.HeaderID
```